# SQL Server select from temp table into another temp table

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have this in a stored procedure:

```
select * into #temp_UNION from 
(
  SELECT 6 AS InteractionType, * FROM history.GetHistoryRewardPointsForIncentiveOption (588,1,6)
   UNION all
   SELECT 8 AS InteractionType, * FROM history.GetHistoryRewardPointsForIncentiveOption (558,1,8)
 ) a
```

which gives:

```
interaction type  historyid         incentiveprogramid       points  
 6              1                  1               50
 6                  1                  4                   50
 6              1                      5                   50
 8                  1                  3                  100
 8              1                  4              100
```

then i have:

```
select tu.InteractionType,ipc.Name,tu.Points from #temp_UNION tu
 inner join Incentive.IncentiveProgramCultures ipc
on tu.IncentiveProgramId = ipc.IncentivePrograms_IncentiveProgramId
 inner join Zinc.Users zu
on zu.Cultures_DefaultCultureId = ipc.IncentiveProgramCultureId
 where zu.UserId = 588


6   India - Q2 Incentive    50
8   India - Q2 Incentive    100
```

now i need to make up HintText which is a field in my #CategoriesTable(previously defined) by using the name i got from above and the points

```
UPDATE #CategoriesTable
SET HintText = CASE WHEN HasAssessment = 1 
                    THEN 'Program ' + tu.name + ' will earn you ' + tu.points
                    ELSE 'With No Assessment' 
                END
```

but i get an error on tu.Name: multi part identifier could not be bound?
how can i achieve? should i make use of another temp table with the 2 rows in it?

here new code:

```
 select * into #temp_UNION from 
(
 SELECT 6 AS InteractionType, * FROM history.GetHistoryRewardPointsForIncentiveOption (588,1,6)
 UNION all
 SELECT 8 AS InteractionType, * FROM history.GetHistoryRewardPointsForIncentiveOption (558,1,8)
 ) a

 select tu.InteractionType,ipc.Name,tu.Points,zu.UserId  into #temp1 from #temp_UNION tu
 inner join Incentive.IncentiveProgramCultures ipc
 on tu.IncentiveProgramId = ipc.IncentivePrograms_IncentiveProgramId
 inner join Zinc.Users zu
 on zu.Cultures_DefaultCultureId = ipc.IncentiveProgramCultureId
 where zu.UserId = 588

Select * from #temp1 t
UPDATE #CategoriesTable
  SET HintText = CASE WHEN HasAssessment = 1 
                    THEN 'Program ' + t.Name + ' and points = ' + t.Points
                    ELSE 'With No Assessment' 
                END 
FROM #temp1 t
WHERE t.userId = #CategoriesTable.UserId

DROP TABLE #temp_UNION 
DROP TABLE #temp1

SELECT *
FROM #CategoriesTable
```

im not getting the #CategoriesTable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must specify the "tu" alias in the update clause

```
UPDATE #CategoriesTable
SET HintText = CASE WHEN HasAssessment = 1 
                THEN 'Program ' + tu.name + ' will earn you ' + tu.points
                ELSE 'With No Assessment' 
            END 
FROM #temp_UNION tu
WHERE tu.? = #CategoriesTable.? --JOIN condition
```

Comment: i want to get the results from the select into a temp table as well please? and THIS temptable must contain the name,points and interactiontype like in my second results set in my OP

Comment: Where is defined #CategoriesTable ?

Comment: i got it right thanks but now the data going back from the stored procedure is the temp table and not #CategoriesTable please see op :)